# How can I keep my elements lining up and staying in the same position?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, window-resize

So i'm building a website, please take a look here. [www.girlzwithmoustaches.com/test2](http://girlzwithmoustaches.com/test2)

I want to line up the black lines on top with the content... However, when i do it on one screen, it looks different on another persons screen. either it's too far out to the right, too short, or the bottom part overlaps..

i'm using squarespace and CSS... i'm trying to position stuff with position:relatve; top:#px; left:#px;

.....

what do i need to add? heres my css...

```
.socialbanner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0px;
    padding-right: 150px;
}

#headerpart {
    width: auto;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    vertical-align: center;
}

#headerpart .socialicons {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    left: 925px;
}

.linebreak {
    color: #434343;
    position: relative;
    top: 60px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 5px;
    max-width: 1100px!important;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 840px!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try creating like this in css. 
Width depends on you.

```
.main {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Comment: so if you look at www.girlzwithmoustaches.com/home2 that's the page i'm working on now... i still have that same issue only with the social media icons... i can't get them to stay in line with the rest of the image underneath.. I want the icons to line up with the right most part of the image under it... plz help man i appreciate your help!